# Chronic Myeloid Leukemia blast percentage

Tags: cancer, hematology, stem-cells

I'm trying to understand the oncogenesis of CML. I have a question about CFC cells and blast cells. Are those the same? I know that in the chronic phase of CML there is a blast percentage of 1-10% of blast cells in the blood. Considering that the total amount of WBC is around 1x10^11 cells/L. That means the blast cells should be around the same order of magnitude. Looking on research articles I found that the amount of CFC (which contains according to my understanding all of the blast cells) are only 1x10^8 cells/L. Thus compromising around 0.1% of the blood count. Where is the other 9.9% coming from?

What cells can be considered as blasts? Only the myeloblasts? Are all blast cells CFC cells? I also know that the average value of CFC cells in the bone marrow is around 10^5 cells how can them go to 10^9 cells?

I read this article https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/9922073/

Comment: Perez  It might be helpful to explain that "CFC" is an abbreviation for "colony forming cells."  Also, could you provide a source for the statement that the "total amount of WBC is around 1x10^11 cells/L."  This is a very complex topic!